# Pass parameters to a webmethod from querystring

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

guys. I'm developing a website with ASP and VB.NET 4. I'm also using the FullCalendar jQuery plugin, but I have a trouble: catching a parameter from querystring to the webmethod in the .asmx. I've tried to refer the querystring property with the Request.QueryString() and it doesn't work.

Here's the webmethod:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="wbsCalendario" %>

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ScriptService> _
Public Class wbsCalendario
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ListarEventos(ByVal starte As String, ByVal ende As String, ByVal v As String) As List(Of CalendarioEvento)
    Dim conexaoSql As New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("praeConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim comandoSql As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spListarEventosCalendario", conexaoSql)
    comandoSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bitPendentes", 0)
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agendamentos", "188,135")
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", FromUnixTimespan(starte))
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", FromUnixTimespan(ende))
    comandoSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veiculo", v)
    Dim eventos As List(Of CalendarioEvento) = New List(Of CalendarioEvento)
    Try
        conexaoSql.Open()
        Dim sdrEventos As SqlDataReader = comandoSql.ExecuteReader
        While sdrEventos.Read
            Dim evento As New CalendarioEvento
            evento.title = StrConv(sdrEventos("vchNome").ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            evento.start = ToUnixTimespan(Convert.ToDateTime(sdrEventos("vchData") + " " + sdrEventos("vchHora")))
            eventos.Add(evento)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        conexaoSql.Close()
    End Try
    comandoSql.Parameters("@bitPendentes").Value = 1
    Try
        conexaoSql.Open()
        Dim sdrEventos As SqlDataReader = comandoSql.ExecuteReader
        While sdrEventos.Read
            Dim evento As New CalendarioEvento
            evento.title = StrConv(sdrEventos("vchNome").ToString, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
            evento.start = ToUnixTimespan(Convert.ToDateTime(sdrEventos("vchData") + " " + sdrEventos("vchHora")))
            evento.color = "#6AB0D8"
            eventos.Add(evento)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        conexaoSql.Close()
    End Try
    Return eventos
End Function

Private Shared Function ToUnixTimespan(ByVal d As DateTime) As Long
    Dim time As New TimeSpan()
    time = d.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
    Return CType(Math.Truncate(time.TotalSeconds), Int64)
End Function

Private Shared Function FromUnixTimespan(ByVal s As String) As DateTime
    Dim time As DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    Return time.AddSeconds(s)
End Function
```

End Class

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a code sample?

Comment: You're really mixing data types here.  Your starte is a string which is passed into FromUnixTimespan(), when then adds the number of seconds represented as a string to an epoch.  Turning on Option Strict and casting the data yourself will help to prevent accidental or unseen mistakes from implicit type casting.  Generally always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the query string are automatically translated into arguments defined on the webmethod.

If you had this Webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Sub DoWork(arg1 As Integer, arg2 As String)
```

And called it by a url of:

```
http://domain/webservice.asmx/DoWork?arg=2&arg2=hello
```

Those two querystring parameters would be translated into the two arguments arg1 and arg2, which could be referenced as normal within the DoWork() method.

Comment: Doesn't work, @Brian. Observe the method receives a start and end parameter from $.ajax()'s POST. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Hmm... and I'm not acessing the .asmx, but the .aspx, where there's the calendar.

Comment: Does the web.config allow for POST data?  Also, have you debugged to see what value, if any (empty string included", is passed to the webmethod?

Comment: Another rather important issue is that your catch statements are completely blank.  if an error occurs, you'll never know about it, and as such will never be able to troubleshoot.  You will not be able to tell what this method is actually doing.  If you're going to use Try/Catch blocks to handle specific error conditions, at least do _something_ with them, not just blindly swallow errors.  put a Throw in there, or some logging or something.  This would likely be the most telling problem with the webmethod.  You will rarely (if ever) want an empty catch.

Comment: it works without a custom param (besides starte and ende). I want to pass a custom param to filter the result set from the database. Thanks.